# IBM DB2 Data Studio - Debugging doesn't work

Tags: db2

I built several stored procedures.

And I "deployed" them with the setting "enable debugging".

And I right click on the stored procedure and click on "DEBUG".

However, it just runs without stopping at the breakpoints I set.

What is wrong with this? Am I missing something?

I'm using the latest Data Studio downloaded from IBM website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click Debug, Data Studio should automatically switch to the Debug perspective (it may take a few seconds). If it does not, try manually switching to the Debug perspective first (Window -> Open perspective -> Other -> Debug), then try running or stepping through your stored procedure.